# How to Find And Delete rows based on some attribute in parquet files across whole bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, etl

I have an s3 bucket containing parquet files organised in a directory structure.

e.g. -

```
s3://my-bucket/data/favorites/property1c/property2b/file1.snappy.parquet
s3://my-bucket/data/favorites/property1c/property2b/file2.snappy.parquet
...
s3://my-bucket/data/favorites/property2c/property5b/file5.snappy.parquet
...
```

Each parquet file contains only 2 columns - `user-id` and `frequency`

My use case is to find and delete all rows corresponding to bunch(a list) of `user-id`s across all paths and all parquet files within the bucket.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: This is almost identical to [this question that appeared at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71126954/aws-s3-how-to-use-spark-job-to-overwrite-data-for-across-multiple-directories). Is it a homework assignment?